# How to use cout and cin without #include in C++?

Tags: c++, cin, cout

I want to make a program in C++ without #include and I don't want to use printf and scanf in my program.

I can use printf and scanf in my program without #include:

```
extern "C"
{
    int printf(const char *format, ...);
    extern int scanf(const char *format, ...);
}
```

But I can't use cout and cin in my program without #include.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: There is no way to do this because the definitions of `cin` and `cout` are not fully standardised.

Comment: @john It is possible. If it is not, how cout and cin was made?

Comment: @Arian How `cin` and `cout` are made is **different** on each compiler. That's what **non-standard** means. That is why it is not possible. If you want to know how `cin` and `cout` are defined on your compiler, then take a look in the header file.

Comment: @john https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Comment: @Arian I said **not fully standardised**. The reference you have quoted specifies the parts that are standard, but they are not fully standardised (nor is very much else in the C++ standard library). The only standard way to access `cin` and `cout` is to include `<iostream>`

Comment: 'cin' and 'cout' are functions that they are in the 'iostream library' (C ++ language), printf and scanf are functions that they are in the 'stdio.h' library (C language)

Comment: @john https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream

Comment: copy and paste the iostream header and all the headers it includes (and so on) manually.

Comment: `std::cin` and `std::cout` aren't functions, they're **objects** with templated types in an inheritance hierarchy. They aren't simple functions you can poop out a prototype for, you absolutely need the headers.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili That is an awesome suggestion. I'm doing that when the next lockdown comes and I'm bored out of my mind. But I bet even then you have to include some system header at some point, that you can't copy paste dependency-less.

Comment: So I guess it's finally happened... The world has gone crazy.

Comment: @nada This hello world example doesn't have a single `#include` and it uses `std::cout` :D https://godbolt.org/z/cPcW83

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Well played. Then that >22k lines of code is the answer to OP's question I guess.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili >22k lines of nonstandard code. Change the compiler and it doesn't work at all. In fact your comment and the link would make a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to use cout and cin without #include in C++?

There is no standard way to do this. `std::cout` and `std::cin` are variables of implementation defined classes. Only way to get the definitions of those classes is to include them from the standard header.

Comment: Slightly hyper technical: this is not implementation-defined, but implementation-specific. In the standard, implementation-defined means that the implementation must document what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly daft answer to this slightly daft (with all due respect) question is to open the #include  in an editor, then cut and paste that code into your own C++ file. Then repeat this process for all the #include statements that were in the original header code and keep repeating until you have all the code actually in your source file.
Result: a (very long) working bit of code without a #include statement.
(I do have a sense of humour).